# はずもない、はずはない、はずがない. Difference and meaning

Tags: grammar, word-choice, translation, meaning, focus-particles

Today listening a song I've heard something I can't understood

```
だけどなれるはずもなくて
```

So i started to gather information about this, but it gets me more confused and furthermore found out two more

> はずはない

and

> はずがない

So, i want to know what is the meaning of this and how should i choose one when speak. Thank you so much in advance for any help you can bring me. I really appreciate it

Comment: So what information have you found that got you confused?

Answer (score 2):

This is another really tough question. They are almost the same, but if I dare to say something, も's version has a nuance of concession, that is, there are many other impossible things and the case mentioned is one of them, so it's not unnatural for it to be impossible. が's nuance is something like it's the last thing that's supposed to be so, if it's different at all.

Answer (score -4):

Hmm im a beginers japanese student. Im just going on a whim here. From what i can see the first one has in the syllables 'ha' 'sa' and then ' ha' while the second has in 'ha' 'su' and then 'ka' i hope this helps