# What is the meaning of "...長く通用するはずもなかった" in this sentence?

Tags: translation, expressions

The context is nothing of special: two girls are talking about a magician that in the past was famous and well renowned, but not anymore in the present days.

One of them tell to the other one:

> 一時期、世間でもてはやされてはいました。しかし彼女の魔法が**長く通用するはずもなかった**

Maybe is (from *shikashi*, because the previous part it's clear):

"But was only a matter of time before her magic lose interest among the people. (the audience).

"長く通用する" is clear (Adv+Suru Vrb), it's about "はずもなかった" that I have perplexities.

Thk U in advance.

Comment: I'd translate it to "of course / as expected, there's no way her magic can be penetrable for long"

Comment: @user4092 I am wondering if I could ask "はずもなかった" is as strong as "はずがなかった". I mean no way describes almost impossible to me. I thought はずもなかった describes there was some way that the magician could have make it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd translate; She had been very popular for some time in the past, but her magic would not have been widely acclaimed among people for a long time.

はずもなかった　implies it could have happened but it didn't happen.

So, the famous magician had the possibility/scenario to be a widely acclaimed magician, but it didn't happen.

In other way, the famous magician might have been a very popular magician, but it isn't.

はずもない is also discussed here.
[はずもない、はずはない、はずがない. Difference and meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28464/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-difference-and-meaning)

Subjunctive mood.
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134926/would-have-done/136965#136965